# How do I uninstall the Mention beta for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-uninstall

I recently installed the [Mention beta for Ubuntu](https://en.mention.net/), a tool to track mentions in social media. The install is a bin file that you have to install from the command line. There's no uninstaller and apt-get remove mention does not find the package. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple install in the `/opt/mention` directory. All you have to do is empty the directory and remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/mention
```

You can paste this code in a terminal window by using Ctrl+Shift+V.